# odoo ImportError: cannot import name UNALTERABLE_COUNTRIES

Tags: package, odoo, odoo-10

I'm facing an error while I select a new db in localhost.
First an `Internal Server Error` Screen comes then when I reload the page,the page will come.
But because of this error we can't view the code in `Edit Form View` and many other problems like we can't edit the reports.
I think this is because of some missing packages.If anyone has a list of what all packages to be installed for the correct working or any other methods to resolve this issue,
Please help..

> Error Log

ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 270, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 258, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/orchid/Documents/client_projects/Aasons/live/live/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 250, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/home/orchid/Documents/client_projects/Aasons/live/live/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 184, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/orchid/Documents/client_projects/Aasons/live/live/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 170, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/orchid/Documents/client_projects/Aasons/live/live/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1307, in **call**
    self.load_addons()
  File "/home/orchid/Documents/client_projects/Aasons/live/live/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1328, in load_addons
    m = **import**('odoo.addons.' + module)
  File "/home/orchid/Documents/client_projects/Aasons/live/live/odoo/odoo/modules/module.py", line 81, in load_module
    execfile(modfile, new_mod.**dict**)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/l10n_fr_pos_cert/**init**.py", line 6, in 
    from ..l10n_fr_certification.models.res_company import UNALTERABLE_COUNTRIES
ImportError: cannot import name UNALTERABLE_COUNTRIES

Comment: could you check the file odoo/addons/l10n_fr_certification/models/res_company.py , does it consist of the global variable UNALTERABLE_COUNTRIES ?

Comment: @OmiHarjani I checked,there is no such global variable

Comment: @OmiHarjani Besides its working in other pc with the same code.So there may be any missing packages in my pc.
Can you show me the list of packages to be installed.

Comment: Please Check your default modules from https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/11.0/addons, if you are missing any.Change the branch according to your odoo version

Comment: @OmiHarjani Its working in other pc with same code.
So I can't change my odoo code.